# What’s a word for people sharing a common culture?

Tags: single-word-requests, ethnonyms

*Tribe* is good.

But what more? I need more words, but exactly mean “they have same culture, traits, etc.”

Comment: This is underspecified. Do you mean like a religion? Or do you mean a whole constellation of cultural items like daily life, religion, government, entertainment, family structure, etc?

Comment: How common, and how much? Does an English speaker in Singapore share the same culture as an English speaker in Miami?

Comment: @JohnLawler There are English speakers in Miami? ¿Desde cuándo? :)

Comment: It isn’t clear whether you’re looking for a demonym, an exonym or an endonym or a cryptonym, an ethnonym, a typonym, or any number of poecilonymic paranyms.

Answer (score 2):

- People

> **We the people of** the United States, in order to form a more perfect
>   union, establish justice, insure domestic tranquility, provide for the
>   common defense, promote the general welfare, and secure the blessings
>   of liberty to ourselves and our posterity, do ordain and establish
>   this Constitution for the United States of America.

- Citizens

> American people, are citizens, **permanent lawful residents** or natives
>   of the United States

- Natives

> **American Indian** and **Alaska Native**. A person having origins in any of
>   the original peoples of North and South America (including Central
>   America) and who maintain tribal affiliation or community attachment.

- Indigenous people

> Indigenous peoples are peoples defined in international or national
>   legislation as having a set of specific rights **based on their
>   historical ties to a particular territory, and their cultural or
>   historical distinctiveness from other populations** that are often
>   politically dominant

- Race and ethnicity

> Race and ethnicity in the United States Census, defined by the federal
>   Office of Management and Budget (OMB) and the United States Census
>   Bureau, are self-identification data items in which **residents choose
>   the race or races with which they most closely identify,** and indicate
>   whether or not they are of Hispanic or Latino origin (the only
>   categories for ethnicity

- Society

> an organized group of persons associated together for religious,
>   benevolent, cultural, scientific, political, patriotic, or other
>   purposes.

and

> a group of people involved with each other through persistent
>   relations, or a large social grouping **sharing the same geographical or
>   social territory, subject to the same political authority and dominant
>   cultural expectations.** Human societies are characterized by patterns
>   of relationships (social relations) between individuals who share a
>   distinctive culture and institutions; a given society may be described
>   as the sum total of such relationships among its constituent members.

Answer (score 1):

*Community* is often used loosely to describe a group with a shared culture (e.g. the Jewish community). However, it is also used in the more general sense of people who live in a given locality.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a word analogous to tribe, try *ethnicity*.

Comment: But ethnically different groups might well share the same culture (or religion, etc), e.g. the acronym MOT, while still using a word for which the OP wants an alternative, sums up the situation better than ethnicity.

Comment: MOT is *Member Of Tribe* --so not exactly an alternative to *tribe*.

Comment: *ethnicity* strongly, even mostly, concerns physical qualities, to which culture is obviously unrelated

Comment: @dilipsarwate MOT is also the common UK term for a certificate to indicate that a car is roadworthy.

Comment: @ChrisSunami My point was that ethnicity is not a particularly analogous word (cf. Dodgie's comment also).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context, "Nation" might be the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the context, but given that if the group is not very large, I think the word your are looking for is either **cult**, or **sect**, if that shared culture considered something rather dangerous.

For more neutral sense, I believe you could use: **camp**, **school**, or **faction**.