# What would you call someone who is part of a culture?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call someone that is a part of a certain culture? culturees? culturettes?

Comment: I don't believe there is a single word for it, just as I believe don't believe there is a single word for somebody who is part of a civilization. It would normally be described in multiple words. (1) *People **who belong to** this culture …* (2) *A **member of** that cultural community …*

Comment: Thank you. This completely answered my question

Comment: Somebody else might provide an actual answer. Just because I can't think of such a word, that doesn't mean it definitely doesn't exist. (It's also difficult to prove a negative in a case like this.)

Comment: Compare: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139756/what-s-a-word-for-people-sharing-a-common-culture

Comment: @Jason Bassford It doesn't matter, it still helped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assumed the word citizen implied a participant in a given culture, as an American citizen is a part of American culture and a Russian or Japanese citizen is a part of that culture.

Comment: What about cultures that cross national boundaries or sub-cultures that aren't defined by national boundaries?